# Trigger action from another swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, swift2

I'm making a TextField which takes a proper date only. Now when I'm using the text field delegate and action methods in the same ViewController class in which my UITextField is, it is working fine. But, I have to make it like a reusable component which can be used in any project by drag and drop. I have two files - MakeDate.swift and ViewController.swift

MakDate.swift --

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class MakeDate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var textField: UITextField!
    var string: String!
    var viewController: UIViewController!
    let characterset = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789")

    init?(textField: UITextField!) {
        self.textField = textField

    }

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        self.string = string

        return true
    }

    func takeProperDateInput() {
        textField.addTarget(textField, action: #selector(self.textChange(_:)), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

    }

    @IBAction func textChange(sender: UITextField) {

        print("\(sender.text!)")

        print("\(sender.text!) && \(self.string)")

        if self.string == "" {
            if sender.text?.characters.count == 2 {
                let index = sender.text?.endIndex.advancedBy(-2)
                sender.text = sender.text?.substringToIndex(index!)
            }
            else if sender.text?.characters.count == 5 {
                let index = sender.text?.endIndex.advancedBy(-2)
                sender.text = sender.text?.substringToIndex(index!)
            }
        }
        if sender.text?.characters.count == 1 && self.string != "" {
            if self.string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(characterset.invertedSet) != nil {
                let index = sender.text?.endIndex.advancedBy(-1)
                sender.text = sender.text?.substringToIndex(index!)
            }
            else if Int(sender.text!) != 1 && Int(sender.text!) != 0 {
                sender.text = "0" + sender.text! + "/"
            }
        }
        else if sender.text?.characters.count == 2 && self.string != "" {
            if Int(string) != 1 && Int(string) != 2 && Int(string) != 0{
                let index = sender.text?.endIndex.advancedBy(-1)
                sender.text = sender.text?.substringToIndex(index!)
            }else {
                sender.text = sender.text! + "/"
            }
        }
        else if sender.text?.characters.count == 4 && self.string != "" {
            if self.string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(characterset.invertedSet) != nil {
                let index = sender.text?.endIndex.advancedBy(-1)
                sender.text = sender.text?.substringToIndex(index!)
            }
        }
        else if sender.text?.characters.count == 5 && self.string != "" {
            if self.string == "/" {
                var yearComponent = sender.text?.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
                let index = sender.text?.endIndex.advancedBy(-2)
                sender.text = sender.text?.substringToIndex(index!)
                sender.text = sender.text! + "0" + yearComponent![1] + "/"
            }else {
                var yearComponent = sender.text?.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
                if Int(yearComponent![1]) > 31 {
                    let index = sender.text?.endIndex.advancedBy(-1)
                    sender.text = sender.text?.substringToIndex(index!)
                }else if Int(yearComponent![1]) > 0 && Int(yearComponent![1]) < 32 {
                    sender.text = sender.text! + "/"
                }else {
                    let index = sender.text?.endIndex.advancedBy(-1)
                    sender.text = sender.text?.substringToIndex(index!)
                }
            }
        }
        else if sender.text?.characters.count == 10 && self.string != "" {
            let index = sender.text?.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)
            if sender.text?.substringFromIndex(index!).rangeOfCharacterFromSet(characterset.invertedSet) != nil {
                let index = sender.text?.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)
                sender.text = sender.text?.substringToIndex(index!)
            } else {
                var yearComponent = sender.text?.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
                if Int(yearComponent![2]) == 0 {
                    let index = sender.text?.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)
                    sender.text = sender.text?.substringToIndex(index!)
                }
            }
        }
        else if sender.text?.characters.count > 10 && self.string != "" {
            let index = sender.text?.endIndex.advancedBy(-1)
            sender.text = sender.text?.substringToIndex(index!)
        }

    }


}
```

and ViewController.swift --

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateInsert: UITextField!
    var dateMaker: MakeDate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
        dateMaker = MakeDate(textField: self.dateInsert)
        self.dateInsert.delegate = self.dateMaker
        self.dateMaker.takeProperDateInput()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

The error i get is `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Hi! Shouldn't you have 'self' rather than the textField inside the target?         textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textChange(_:)), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

Comment: @ohr oh god! yes! and i was searching all over what is going wrong! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a textfield class with the default properties and implement in the view controller not a nsobject to send a textfield as parameter:

```
class baseTextfield: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {


}

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var dateInsert: UIBaseTextField!
}
```

The properties are of the textfield, not of the view.